# How to add 5 hours to a datetime stamp?

Tags: extensions, global-configuration, date, jdate, timezone

I've set up an edit column in the database, it stamps the correct time whenever a change is made to the database entry. For some odd reason whenever this datetime displays it displays 5 hours behind the time stamp in the database.

The only thing I can figure to do is add 5 hours to the time, but I can't seem to get any combinations from the online examples to simply add 5 hours to the stamp. Was hoping someone could help me out.

```
if ($comment->deleted == 1) {  } else { 

   $db = JFactory::getDbo();
   $db->setQuery('SELECT editdate 
                  FROM #__jcomments
                  WHERE id = ' . $comment->id .'');
   $db->loadResult();
   $edit = $db->loadResult();

   if ($edit > 0) { 
   echo JHtml::_('date', $edit, JText::_('l F j Y g:ia'));  } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `JHtml::date()` accounts for user's timezone, which, if not set, defaults to site's timezone (set in Global Configuration). Pass another argument with value `null` to leave the date as is. Also, because you're using a hardcoded string for format, you don't need to wrap it in `JText::_()`:

```
echo JHtml::_('date', $edit, 'l F j Y g:ia', null);
```

You should also remove first instance of `$db->loadResult()`. By having two of these you are running the query twice.

Comment: Thank you. Just curious, is that the same in every case? If you have a query and then **$db->loadAssocList(); $a = $db->loadAssocList();** or **$db->loadColumn(); $a = array_count_values($db->loadColumn());** can that first one always be gotten rid of?

Comment: Yes. This true not just for JDatabase but for all PHP code.